# Wordpress url rewriting with location header

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, iframe

I use iframes to load standlone php file or others websites into wordpress, but i cant get this working for other website. How i can get it working ?

I use the following htaccess which exclude app.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ wp-content/themes/lily/app.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in app.php:

```
<?php
    $appid = strtolower($_GET['appid']);
    if($appid && file_exists($appid.'/'.$appid.'.php')){
        header('Location: wp-content/themes/lily/apps/'.$appid.'/'.$appid.'.html');
    }elseif($appid && $appid == 'rappels'){
        header('Location:http://google.fr'); // for exemple
    } else {
    header('Location: wp-content/themes/lily/includes/noapp.php');
 } ?>
```

And i use js to generate the iframes.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: The file_exists fails, but if i use include, it's working. I think i need to use Options +FollowSymlinks in the htaccess.

Comment: Yep, I'd recommend trying to add that to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I already have done it, still not working :(